# Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown error 1049

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

This should be an easy one.  I am writing a toy application in JPA with Eclipselink and not using SSL.  When the entity manager is called I get the message below.  I am guessing I am missing a parameter in my persistence.xml file, but the exception is not very specific.

```
    [EL Info]: 2016-08-23 13:28:04.574--ServerSession(1586463432)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
    Tue Aug 23 13:28:05 EDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
...
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown error 1049
    Error Code: 1049
@ em= Error message: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown error 1049
    Error Code: 1049
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:    Unknown error 1049
    Error Code: 1049
    at    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at com.ruleagents.hero.Main.main(Main.java:48)
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown error 1049
    Error Code: 1049
    at  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 5 more
...
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ruleagents.hero.Main.main(Main.java:62)
```

This is the persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CharacterManager"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
       org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <class>com.ruleagents.hero.Hero</class>
    <class>com.ruleagents.hero.Logon</class>
    <!-- class>com.ruleagents.hero.Stat</class -->
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CharacterManager" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        <property name="useSSL" value="false" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is how it is called:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory getEMF (){
    try {
        if (emf == null){
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CharacterManager");
...
EntityManager em = null;
try {
   em = getEMF().createEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   em.persist(user);
```

What do I need to change to get this to connect to MySql?  Thank!

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html the useSSL defaults to true on  MySQL 5.5.45+.  Try specifying false - see the link for how to add properties to your URL

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error code 1049 seems to be unknown database.

```
Error: 1049 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_BAD_DB_ERROR)

Message: Unknown database '%s'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html